# Updating an item of ListView from another Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I'm creating a ListView in Activity A which contains some kind of Post views, each of them have its own like button. 
Every post can be viewed in Activity B as a single post (Which I re-read from server because there's more info to present).

I'm trying to figure a way that if a user click the like button on Activity B (Which updates the server & UI of its own Activity (B)),
would update the UI of the same post 
(which I have its ID and position in the list ofcourse) 
on Activity A. .

Any thoughts?

Comment: how you handle this man? I have a same situation now :(

Comment: The solution was actually pretty simple. What I did is to update the data the adapter had, in my case it was amount of likes on a specific post. So for an instance I call my posts list and called a specific post add like method: post.get(I).add like();   after that just called adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); and that's it!

Comment: Okay, now assume that you have a fragment and have a list with all posts, then user clicked on a category and redirected to category fragment and finally by click on post goes to post activity! and in post activity user liked that! and then press back, by your solution we can handle this section, but when user press back again and go to all post list! how can handle that! we have 2 list with two different data :( ( G+ app like! )

Comment: If you want to update the post likes on the All Post List and on the category list you'll have to update both lists data's and call notifyDatasetChanged(); on both adapters.

Comment: Yeah, but how should I acquire particular post position on each list data's? please look at  my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374445/update-common-post-in-different-listview-with-different-data-in-adapter/27374579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your **adapter data** for ListView in another activity and once you back to `Activity A` in `onResume()` you can call `notifyDatasetChanged()` to your adapter and refresh your `ListView` with newly updated data.

Comment: Ok, one more question. How do I let the first Activity know that something need to be changed?

Comment: For standard UI updation you have to update your UI components at `onResume()` of your Activity if your Activity is in Pause mode and for standard data changes you have to make interface for that.

Comment: Got it all figured. Thank you!

Comment: @user370305 Okay, now assume that you have a fragment and have a list with all posts, then user click on a category and redirected to category fragment and finally by click on post goes to post activity! and in post activity user liked that! and then press back, by your solution we can handle this section, but when user press back again and go to all post list! how can handle that! we have 2 list with two different data :( ( G+ app like! - do you know how them handle it? )

Comment: @MAY3AM - If all post list available in different activity then whenever you navigate to post activity don't close or destroy previous activity just open post activity and by like post close activity so your previous activity just resume from pause mode.

Comment: @user370305 I've just asked question with more description here, Please take a look at there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374445/update-common-post-in-different-listview-with-different-data-in-adapter/27374579